# Taking a logarithmic derivative of a function

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

I have the following expression:

$ \log{\left(1 - \frac{r}{r_{s}} \right)} $

which I would like to take the following derivative of (and where $r_{s}$ is a constant):

$ \frac{d\left(\log{\left(1 - \frac{r}{r_{s}} \right)}\right)}{d \log{(r)}} $

What kind of strategies could I employ to find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $t=\log r$ then $e^t=r$ substituting in your expression you have to find

$$\frac{d}{dt}\log(1-\frac{e^t}{r_n})$$
after differentiating retain the value of $r$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that you have log(u). Then apply d(log(u))/du = 1 / u. Now, since you want, I guess, the derivative with respect to "r" and since u = 1 - r / rs, then du/dr = - 1 / rs and so,
 d(log[1 - r / rs])/dr = d(Log(u))/du * du/dr = 1 / (r - rs).